# calculation average from a few month at the turn of the year for 3 diffrent indexs and for 30 years

Tags: r, average

I do not have a really date values. I have one column with Year and another with Month. And 3 more columns for 3 diffrent indexes.There is one index value for one month. (so 12 months per year for 30 years,. It is lots numbers)  So I´d like to see the average value from a few month. 
I need the information about this index to predict pollen season in summer time. So I would like to have a average for winter months (like Dec-Jan_Feb_Mars) for NAO and also average for winter months for AO and SO. (so 3 average for 3 index). But also I ´d like to receive this value not only for one year but for all years. I think the complicate story is because Dec 1988 - Jan 1989- Feb 1989 (so it is a average for a few month at the turn of the years). If I succsse with this I will do diffrent combination of months.

```
Year Month   NAO    AO   SO
1   1988     1  1.02  0.26 -0.1
2   1988     2  0.76 -1.07 -0.4
3   1988     3 -0.17 -0.20  0.6
4   1988     4 -1.17 -0.56  0.1
5   1988     5  0.63 -0.85  0.9
6   1988     6  0.88  0.06  0.1
7   1988     7 -0.35 -0.14  1.0
8   1988     8  0.04  0.25  1.5
9   1988     9 -0.99  1.04  1.8
10  1988    10 -1.08  0.03  1.4
11  1988    11 -0.34 -0.03  1.7
12  1988    12  0.61  1.68  1.2
13  1989     1  1.17  3.11  1.5
14  1989     2  2.00  3.28  1.2
...
366 2018     6  1.09  0.38 -0.1
367 2018     7  1.39  0.61  0.2
368 2018     8  1.97  0.84 -0.3


index$Month<-as.character(index$Month)
#define function to compute average by consecutive season of interest/month_combination
compute_avg_season <- function(index, month_combination){
index<-index%>%
  mutate(date=paste(Year,Month, "01",sep="-")) %>%
  mutate(date=as.Date(date,"%Y-%b-%d")) %>%
  arrange(date)%>%
  mutate(winter_mths=ifelse(Month %in% month_combination, 1, NA))
index<-setDT(index)[,id :=rleid(winter_mths)]%>%
  filter(!is.na(winter_mths))%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  summarise(mean_winter_NAO=mean(NAO, na.rm = TRUE)),
```

> Error: unexpected ',' in:
>   "group_by(id)%>%
>   summarise(mean_winter_NAO=mean(NAO, na.rm = TRUE)),"
>   summarise(mean_winter_NAO=mean(NAO, na.rm = TRUE),
>   + mean_winter_AO=mean(AO, na.rm = TRUE),
>   + mean_winter_SO=mean(SO, na.rm=TRUE))
>   Error in mean(NAO, na.rm = TRUE) : object 'NAO' not found
>   View(index)

Why do I have such error?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, add some data to use, to copy and paste in R, maybe updating the question with the result of `dput(your_data_here)` if they can be posted. Also, try to share any kind of attempt you've done, to have more chance to have an answer, and not getting downvotes or your question close. In the end, a desired clear output is necessary, because in this case you are asking a couple of questions in one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R help calculate a mean for several months over several years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53842220/r-help-calculate-a-mean-for-several-months-over-several-years)

Comment: Thank you. The next time I will try do my best.  And the R help calculate a mean for several months over several years it iis not the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the answer to the new insights from your comments:

```
# load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

# pre-processing
index$Month <- as.character(index$Month) # Month is factor, make it character
colnames(index)[1] <- "Year" # simplify name of the Year column


# define a function to compute average by consecutive season of interest/month_combination (do not modify this function)
compute_avg_season <- function(df, month_combination) {

    # mark combination of months as 1, else NA
    df <- df %>% 
      # correction month MAY
      mutate(Month = replace(Month, Month=="MAI", "MAY")) %>%
      # create date
      mutate(date = paste(Year, Month, "01", sep="-")) %>%
      mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%Y-%b-%d")) %>%
      # sort by date (you want average by consecutive months: DEC, JAN, FEB, MAR)
      arrange(date) %>%
      mutate(winter_mths = ifelse(Month %in% month_combination, 1, NA))


    # add index for each set of months of interest and compute mean by index value
    df <- setDT(df)[, id := rleid(winter_mths)] %>% 
      filter(!is.na(winter_mths)) %>% 
      group_by(id) %>% 
      summarise(mean_winter_NAO = mean(NAO, na.rm = TRUE), 
                mean_winter_AO = mean(AO, na.rm = TRUE), 
                mean_winter_SO = mean(SO, na.rm = TRUE))

    return(df)

    }


# Use the above-defined function to compute mean values by desired month combination: 

# set the month combination
month_combination <- c("DEC", "JAN", "FEB", "MAR")

 # compute mean values by month combination
compute_avg_season(index, month_combination)
```

Comment: Not really. I need the information about this index to predict pollen season in summer time. So I would like to have a average for winter months (like Dec-Jan_Feb_Mars) for NAO and also average for winter months for AO and SO. (so 3 average for 3 index). But also I ´d like to receive this value not only for one year but for my all years. I think the complicate story is because Dec 1988 - Jan 1989- Feb 1989 (so it is a average for a few month at the turn of the years). If I succsse with this I will do diffrent combination of months.

Comment: I do not have a really date values. I have one column with Year and another with Month. And 3 more columns for 3 diffrent indexes.There is one index value for one month. (so 12 months per year for 30 years,. It is lots numbers)  So I´d like to see the average value from a few month.

Comment: @Ewa I updated the answer. It should work, but a reproducible example from your dataset is always useful. You can extract the first, say, 10 rows with `dput(head(df, 10))`

Comment: Hi Luminita, thank you for all. Sorry for delayed answer but my computer completely broken after Christmas. I still fighting with this index.

Comment: > dput(head(Index, 10))
structure(list(ï..Year = c(1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 
1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L), Month = structure(c(5L, 4L, 
9L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L), .Label = c("APR", "AUG", "DEC", 
"FEB", "JAN", "JUL", "JUN", "MAI", "MAR", "NOV", "OCT", "SEP"
), class = "factor"), NAO = c(1.02, 0.76, -0.17, -1.17, 0.63, 
0.88, -0.35, 0.04, -0.99, -1.08), AO = c(0.26, -1.07, -0.2, -0.56, 
-0.85, 0.06, -0.14, 0.25, 1.04, 0.03), SO = c(-0.1, -0.4, 0.6, 
0.1, 0.9, 0.1, 1, 1.5, 1.8, 1.4)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: > Index <- read.csv("Index.csv")
> Index 
    ï..Year Month   NAO    AO   SO
1      1988   JAN  1.02  0.26 -0.1
2      1988   FEB  0.76 -1.07 -0.4
3      1988   MAR -0.17 -0.20  0.6
4      1988   APR -1.17 -0.56  0.1
5      1988   MAI  0.63 -0.85  0.9
6      1988   JUN  0.88  0.06  0.1
7      1988   JUL -0.35 -0.14  1.0
8      1988   AUG  0.04  0.25  1.5
9      1988   SEP -0.99  1.04  1.8
10     1988   OCT -1.08  0.03  1.4
11     1988   NOV -0.34 -0.03  1.7
12     1988   DEC  0.61  1.68  1.2
13     1989   JAN  1.17  3.11  1.5
14     1989   FEB  2.00  3.28  1.2

Comment: I´´d like to calculated an average for Dec + Jan +Feb + Mar for each Year for each index. I´d like to receive Dec-Jan-Feb-Mar 1998 NAO for all year and all index. And after that after that I´d like to receive different combination of months i.e. Jan-Feb 1998 NAO.

Comment: Hi Luminita, I did as you showed me, but there is some error(Please look at my post). I corrected month MAY in my csv.  and I got error in this place: > summarise(mean_winter_NAO=mean(NAO, na.rm = TRUE),
+ mean_winter_AO=mean(AO, na.rm = TRUE),
+ mean_winter_SO=mean(SO, na.rm=TRUE))
Error in mean(NAO, na.rm = TRUE) : object 'NAO' not found. What was happend?

Comment: Hi Ewa. It is difficult for me to understand the code example you provided because it is not properly formatted. Please check out here how it can be done: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: However, from what I see, you modified the `compute_avg_season` function. It should not be modified. I updated the answer to work with a dataframe that is named `index` (I think this is what you were trying to do).